# Why does Picard order 'Tea. Earl Grey. Hot.'?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, computers, jean-luc-picard

The *Enterprise-D*'s computer shows us on multiple occasions that it can deal with natural language input.  One notable example of extended conversation is in *TNG* '11001010':

> PICARD: Computer, explain Red Alert.
>
> COMPUTER: Initiated as a programmed response. The magnetic field containing the antimatter had weakened. There was no fail-safe available.
>
> PICARD: Why wasn't I notified?
>
> COMPUTER: Unknown.
>
> PICARD: Present condition?
>
> COMPUTER: The magnetic field is now restored. Containment is restored. Propulsion is at maximum efficiency.

This continues for a while, so I shan't bore you with the details.

The Computer can even deal with Lwaxana Troi's talking to it as if it were a person:

> LWAXANA: Hello, computer? Is Commander Riker still on the Bridge?
>
> COMPUTER: Negative. Riker is currently in holodeck three.
>
> LWAXANA: Holodeck? Where is that?
>
> COMPUTER: Follow the comm. panel lights. They will lead you there.

(*TNG* 'Manhunt')

So, if the computer can deal with natural language requests, **why does Picard order 'Tea. Earl Grey. Hot.' rather than something more like 'Replicate a cup of hot Earl Grey tea?'**

Comment: Why would he use a long-winded command like 'replicate a cup of hot Earl Grey tea' when just 'tea Earl Grey' works? What I wonder is, why doesn't he just say 'the usual'?

Comment: @user14111 it's just that he (and most others) normally speak to the computer in natural language, except for this particular order.

Comment: Because he knows what happened to Kirk's chicken sandwich and coffee?

Comment: related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64605/what-would-the-replicator-do-if-picard-ordered-hot-earl-grey-tea

Comment: Presumably because that's how you speak to a waiter. I don't think people in Ten Forward or Quark's ever go "would you mind pouring me a drink", either.

Comment: Your example from 11001010 isn't necessarily natural. It's still as short as possible. I can't think of any better way to shorten/simplify "Why wasn't I notified".

Comment: @Valorum I think Andrew Biner's answer does address the question, so I'm happy to close it!

Comment: @OftenRight - I think it's pretty obvious that Picard is shortcutting the menu. "*Tea*", "**What Kind of tea**", [sigh] "*Earl Grey*", "**Specify Temperature**, [sigh] "*Hot*".

Comment: @OftenRight Maybe, just maybe he sometimes orders Tea. Lipton. Iced.

Comment: It was mentioned that the Galaxy class was the most advanced starship ever built by the Federation. This implies that the computer is more advanced as well. Older models might not have been able to understand conversational speech so well and Picard might simply be in the habit of ordering food/drink that way

Comment: @geewhiz very intriguing theory!