# In the 2009 movie, why was Spock's mother part of the Vulcan High Council?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-2009

In the 2009 movie, after destroying the drill boring into Vulcan, Spock goes to rescue the Vulcan High Council — "those tasked with protecting and preserving our cultural history." He goes on to state with confidence, "My parents will be among them." We later see this is true, that his (human) mother was indeed with this group. Moreover, it appeared as if she belonged there as a member, and not because she had any arranged meeting with the group of which Spock may have known.

Something had always bothered me with this scene... it was a little too convenient that Spock would have a legitimate, mission-oriented reason to go after his parents, that he would know where they were, and even that they would be in the same place. Today it finally hit me: why would a human be part of the Vulcan High Council, especially with such prejudice demonstrated in the scene covering Spock's graduation, which couldn't have been too many years prior?

Comment: This has nagged at the back of my mind for a while now, where I wasn't even aware of the question... until today when I stumbled upon an answer. I just want to document it: I already have a canned response that will take just a few minutes to post.

Comment: Y'know you can ask and answer from the same form..?

Comment: I see no evidence that she's a member of the council.

Comment: After earthquakes, why couldn't she come to see her husband?

Comment: I felt that my answer was pretty comprehensive. Is there anything else you'd like to see before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 21):

Although [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Amanda_Grayson_(alternate_reality)) <s>states</s> used to state that Amanda Grayson is a member of the Vulcan Council, both the [novelisation](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_(novel)) and the [film script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Trek.html) strongly suggest that she's actually present to support her husband rather than as a member of the Council in her own right.

> Deep within the sanctuary as their world crumbled around them, six
> sets of hands rested on the katric ark. Vulcan’s single most sacred
> object, it purportedly held the katra or soul of the ancient known as
> Surak. Together with its contents, the ark represented all that was
> good and noble and revered in the humanoid species that called the
> desert planet home. Linked together by mind-meld as they sought to
> shut out the chaos rising in intensity around them, **the six Elders**
> chanted softly among themselves.
>
> **Among them** was Amanda Grayson’s husband. Though she could not by
> herself join the collective mind-meld, **it was important to Sarek that
> she was present.**
>
> <sub><sup>Star Trek : Movie Tie-In Novelization</sup></sub>

and

> **INT. KATRIC ARK CHAMBER - DAY**
>
> Spock RACES through the tunnels as the world SHAKES around him -- he
> enters the massive ARK CHAMBER -- sees, atop the enormous stairs, FIVE
> VULCAN ELDERS, Sarek among them, hands placed on the sarcophagus-like
> ark. Mind melding with it. **Amanda is here too, kneeling beside
> Sarek** -- and she sees her son, who is now RUNNING toward them -- she
> stands:
>
> <sub><sup>Star Trek Script</sup></sub>

Comment: @PaulDraper - A quick google suggests that at least a couple of dozen people have been led astray by the same issue. Memory Alpha is awesome, but it's often got a lot of unsubstantiated claims on it

Answer (score 8):

In the 1989 book, [Spock's World by Diane Duane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spock's_World), Vulcan Elder T'Pau passes her katra to Spock's Mother.

> Kirk, Spock, and McCoy ... are interrupted by the news that T'Pau, a Vulcan elder and possibly the most respected living figure on Vulcan at that point, is dying. T'Pau makes the decision to transfer her katra (in a sense, her soul) to [Spock's Mother], instead of another Vulcan, proving her trust in certain members of the human race.

This would give Spock's mother the ability to claim a place with the Vulcan High Council.

The wikipedia article later goes on to claim:

> [Spock's World] is a favorite of the 2009 film's co-writer Roberto Orci.

Comment: 1. wrong timeline, and 2. the events of *Star Trek* take place prior to the events of *TOS*, T'Pau would have been alive at the time the question is dealing with.

Comment: @Keen - ... because time travel. With the timeline altered, T'Pau may have died earlier, but still transferred her katra to Amanda.

Comment: To T'Pau, it's just china in her hands.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: Or T'Pau might have transferred her katra to anyone else, or anyone else might have transferred their katra to Amanda. What happened in another timeline cannot possibly provide any clues to what happened in the Abramsverse timeline.

Answer (score 0):

Not having read the books I cannot use them as a frame of reference, but instead I will go to the *Star Trek* universe for the original period to the last movies.Throughout all of them Sarek has always valued his wife's presence by his side as well as her advice, support and love. It makes sense that at a time like this he would want her with him in what were to be their and Vulcan's final hours. The question of whether or not she was on the high council is moot. She is by his side, because that has always been her place.

Answer (score -3):

No. She does not appear with the chamber of council members, therefore, we can assume that she was not one of them.

Comment: She does appear with them. She's right behind them when Spock walks in